# Working rights for non-EU spouse

Tags: working-visas, eu-spouses

I would really appreciate your assistance and any tips or resources that you may be aware of.

I was born in Ireland and moved to Australia at a young age. I am fortunate to hold dual citizenship with Australia and Ireland. My Australian husband of 10 years and I wish to pursue our dream of living in mainland Europe together.

I know that he would likely be able to get an Irish work permit as my spouse, but we are hoping to reside in France or Spain. As a pilot, he has some exciting opportunities with European airlines (for which he has all of the appropriate licences, and for which there is a demand at the moment).

However, I have found it difficult to find information about his ability to work in Europe if he does have an Irish spousal work permit or if this is required at all. I would not be working initially but we would have sufficient funds to support ourselves with savings and rent, health insurance etc. in Europe for at least a year.

Can he work in another EU country on an Irish spousal visa? Will he have working rights as my spouse if we move directly to France or Spain? Would he be able to apply for a work permit if I am not working?

If he is able to find work with an airline such as EasyJet, would he have issues flying in and out of EU countries on a spousal visa?

I would really appreciate any details or links. It is a big decision to make and went want to ensure a smooth transition as best we can. Thank you!

Comment: One issue I know nothing about but that might be relevant is whether his qualification as a pilot would be easily recognized in Europe. It could be worth asking about that in a follow-up question.

Comment: See also https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/7138/options-for-eu-person-to-move-to-spain-without-a-having-secured-apriori-a-job https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/7284/blue-card-doubt-and-financial-evidence and https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/2989/requirements-to-move-to-eu-country-as-an-eu-citizen-with-an-australian-non-eu

Answer (score 1):

Your husband is not allowed to work (or even reside without working) in another EU country on an Irish Spousal Visa. As your spouse, he would be allowed to work in France or Spain if you yourself qualify for EU freedom of movement. If you are not working, that means having health insurance and being able to show some income or savings that puts you over the threshold to receive welfare benefits (in practice something like €15000 in savings or €500 a month should be enough). That would be the most natural route to secure residency.

Comment: Can the husband's income be used to "show some income ... that puts you over the threshold"?

Comment: @phoog I wondered about that too, I think I commented on it in another answer. In practice, it seems difficult to rely on income from work the first time around. But what about other type of income? I am not entirely sure.